# node.js remove file

Tags: node.js

How do I delete a file with node.js?

http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_rename_oldpath_newpath_callback

I don't see a remove command?

Answer (score 1080, accepted):

I think you want to use [`fs.unlink`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_unlink_path_callback).

More info on `fs` can be found [here](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_file_system).

Comment: I believe it comes from the POSIX standard. But you'd think they could add a `delete` alias!

Comment: @Nick or a `rmFile` alias

Comment: @PixnBits or an `rm` alias if they have `rmdir` methods

Comment: for Meteor user, you may want to use `fs.unlinkSync()`

Comment: I think you should provide a whole example, links can change.

Comment: We could rename it ourselves (`function del_file(params) { return fs.unlink(params) }`)!  At least, that works in python!  Not sure about JS / Node

Comment: you may want to use fs Promises API https://stackoverflow.com/a/59116941/3006185

Answer (score 357):

You can call `fs.unlink(path, callback)` for Asynchronous unlink(2) or `fs.unlinkSync(path)` for Synchronous unlink(2).
Where `path` is file-path which you want to remove.

For example we want to remove `discovery.docx` file from `c:/book` directory. So my file-path is `c:/book/discovery.docx`. So code for removing that file will be,

```
var fs = require('fs');
var filePath = 'c:/book/discovery.docx'; 
fs.unlinkSync(filePath);
```

Answer (score 95):

If you want to check file before delete whether it exist or not. So, use [fs.stat](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_stat_path_callback) or [fs.statSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_stat_path_callback) (**Synchronous**) instead of `fs.exists`. Because according to the latest node.js [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_exists_path_callback), `fs.exists` now **deprecated**.

For example:-

```
 fs.stat('./server/upload/my.csv', function (err, stats) {
   console.log(stats);//here we got all information of file in stats variable

   if (err) {
       return console.error(err);
   }

   fs.unlink('./server/upload/my.csv',function(err){
        if(err) return console.log(err);
        console.log('file deleted successfully');
   });  
});
```

Comment: What if I check it exists, but it's blocked by another process - or, I check it exists, and it's fine, but then another process randomly blocks it before I'm able to delete. How can I block straight after checking? then wouldnt I not be able to delete as its blocked

Comment: Note that fs.exists() is deprecated, but fs.existsSync() is not.

Comment: There's a reason it's deprecated: often times you creates a race condition if you check that a file exists before deleting it. Instead, you should only call `fs.unlink`, and if the file doesn't exist, you'll have an `ENOENT` error in the callback. No need to check before trying to unlink.

Comment: @ZachB why delete operation `fs.unlink` perform when file not existed, so my view is that check file before remove.

Comment: You shouldn't check if it exists if there are multiple threads or processes that might be using or trying to delete the same file, in which case your check that the file exists will become invalid between the time you check that it exists and the time you try to delete it. Just check for the ENOENT error code in the `unlink` callback. If that error occurred, the file didn't exist. Look at Searene's answer for example.

Comment: The big problem with this approach is that it throws errors for non-exceptional cases. Major debugging a real PITA. Node should have taken a different approach, IMO.

Answer (score 64):

**2020 Answer**

With the release of node `v14.14.0` you can now do.

```
fs.rmSync("path/to/file", {
    force: true,
});
```

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsrmsyncpath-options

Comment: The docs say force means: `force <boolean> When true, exceptions will be ignored if path does not exist. Default: false.`

Comment: Jumping to this answer, it's missing some context.  Need to add `var fs = require('fs');` to the beginning.

Comment: Using `fs/promises` and `await fs.rm(resultsFile, { force: true })` is probably better, to avoid the sync call.

Answer (score 56):

I don't think you have to check if file exists or not, `fs.unlink` will check it for you.

```
fs.unlink('fileToBeRemoved', function(err) {
    if(err && err.code == 'ENOENT') {
        // file doens't exist
        console.info("File doesn't exist, won't remove it.");
    } else if (err) {
        // other errors, e.g. maybe we don't have enough permission
        console.error("Error occurred while trying to remove file");
    } else {
        console.info(`removed`);
    }
});
```

Comment: how can i get previous Image name in Our Controller?

Answer (score 31):

Here is a small snippet of I made for this purpose,

```
var fs = require('fs');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');

fs.exists('./www/index.html', function(exists) {
  if(exists) {
    //Show in green
    console.log(gutil.colors.green('File exists. Deleting now ...'));
    fs.unlink('./www/index.html');
  } else {
    //Show in red
    console.log(gutil.colors.red('File not found, so not deleting.'));
  }
});
```

Comment: Async exists is deprecated https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_exists_path_callback

Comment: What if the file gets deleted by others after you check with `fs.exists` and before you remove it with `fs.unlink`? It could happen.

Comment: You should not check if a file exists before attempting to unlink it. Just call `unlink`, and if it doesn't exist, handle the `ENOENT` error. Otherwise you can create a race condition.

Answer (score 24):

**2019 and Node 10+ is here**. Below the version using sweet *async/await* way.

Now no need to wrap `fs.unlink` into Promises nor to use additional packages (like `fs-extra`) anymore.

Just use native [fs Promises API](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_promises_api).

```
const fs = require('fs').promises;

(async () => {
  try {
    await fs.unlink('~/any/file');
  } catch (e) {
    // file doesn't exist, no permissions, etc..
    // full list of possible errors is here 
    // http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/unlink.2.html#ERRORS
    console.log(e);
  }
})();
```

[Here is](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_unlink_path) `fsPromises.unlink` spec from Node docs.

Also please note that fs.promises API marked as experimental in Node 10.x.x (but works totally fine, though), and no longer experimental since `11.14.0`.

Answer (score 16):

You can do the following thing

```
const deleteFile = './docs/deleteme.txt'
if (fs.existsSync(deleteFile)) {
    fs.unlink(deleteFile, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        console.log('deleted');
    })
}
```

> Asynchronously removes a file or symbolic link. No arguments other than a possible exception are given to the completion callback.

> fs.unlink() will not work on a directory, empty or otherwise. To remove a directory, use fs.rmdir().

[More details](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/unlink.2.html)

Answer (score 14):

Simple and sync

```js
if (fs.existsSync(pathToFile)) {
  fs.unlinkSync(pathToFile)
}
```

Answer (score 10):

As the accepted answer, use `fs.unlink` to delete files.

But according to [Node.js documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_stat_path_callback)

> Using `fs.stat()` to check for the existence of a file before calling `fs.open()`, `fs.readFile()` or `fs.writeFile()` is not recommended. Instead, user code should open/read/write the file directly and handle the error raised if the file is not available.
>
> To check if a file exists without manipulating it afterwards, `fs.access()` is recommended.

to check files can be deleted or not, Use `fs.access` instead

```
fs.access('/etc/passwd', fs.constants.R_OK | fs.constants.W_OK, (err) => {
  console.log(err ? 'no access!' : 'can read/write');
});
```

Comment: This is a good answer, with a Node.js reference. most people will use `unlink` directly because they know they have rights to delete the file. But `fs.access` is a good alternative if they need to check before deletion. But I think if they need to check if a file exists without manipulating it afterwards, they should naturally use `fs.stat`, `fs.access` has a different purpose in my humble opinion.

Comment: the reason why the documentation recommends against checking for existance is because that information can change between your call to fs.stat/fs.access and the actual operation. For example the file could exist when you call fs.access and then be deleted before you call fs.unlink, or the permissions could change between the two calls. Since you have to handle the error codes of fs.unlink in that case anyways there's no point in calling fs.stat or fs.access.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question that was being asked, which is specifically about how to remove the file. (As opposed to, how to know whether you have rights to remove it.)

Answer (score 10):

Here below my code which works fine.

```
         const fs = require('fs');
         fs.unlink(__dirname+ '/test.txt', function (err) {            
              if (err) {                                                 
                  console.error(err);                                    
              }                                                          
             console.log('File has been Deleted');                           
          });
```

Comment: I like this answer the best because it's the simplest complete and correct answer for those that want to know how run something after the unlink completes and don't care about customizing the error message.

Comment: why are you using __dirname? I wonder if we could place a relative path instead of full path?

Comment: I'm using Node / Express / Multer to enable file attachments through REST POST calls. How can you expose fs.unlink in the Node / Express framework so that it can process REST DELETE calls? Posts are exposed with an app.post(...) so is something similar needed to expose the delete request? Multer may not be needed for DELETES, but what has me stuck is how to expose a workable DELETE.

Answer (score 9):

**2022 Answer**

Never do any sync operation in Nodejs

To asynchronously delete a file,

```
const { unlink } = require('fs/promises');
(async function(path) {
  try {
    await unlink(path);
    console.log(`successfully deleted ${path}`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('there was an error:', error.message);
}
})('/tmp/hello');
```

ref: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#promise-example

It is recommended to check file exists before deleting using **access** or **stat**

```
import { access, constants } from 'fs';

const file = 'package.json';

// Check if the file exists in the current directory.
access(file, constants.F_OK, (err) => {
  console.log(`${file} ${err ? 'does not exist' : 'exists'}`);
});
```

ref: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsaccesspath-mode-callback

Comment: No need to "try catch" if `unlink` is a promise. Best practice would be to use promise like ".then .catch"

Comment: @Marco Please provide documentation backing up your claim that using async/await syntax is not a best practice.

Comment: @RohnAdams Not talking async/await syntax - that looks fine. Just saying that 
 the try/catch block is redundant and can get messy since a promise gives you the `.then` `.catch` syntax.

Comment: @Marco can you provide documentation that suggests that using the try/catch syntax with async/await is not best practice?

Comment: Thank you @RohnAdams. You got me there. I can't find anything more than Promise chain error handling is the modern way. Please then allow me to restate my comment by changing 'Best practice' to 'Modern'.

Answer (score 6):

- `fs.unlinkSync()` if you want to remove files synchronously and
- `fs.unlink()` if you want to remove it asynchronously.

[Here](https://flaviocopes.com/how-to-remove-file-node/) you can find a good article.

Answer (score 6):

## Just `rm -rf` it

```js
require("fs").rmSync(file_or_directory_path_existing_or_not, {recursive: true, force: true});
// Added in Node.js 14.14.0.
```

with `require("fs").rmSync` or `require("fs").rm`.

Answer (score 3):

you can use [del](https://www.npmjs.com/package/del) module to remove one or more files in the current directory. what's nice about it is that protects you against deleting the current working directory and above.

```
const del = require('del');
del(['<your pathere here>/*']).then( (paths: any) => {
   console.log('Deleted files and folders:\n', paths.join('\n'));
});
```

Comment: If you need to delete multiple files, this is a great option! Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

You may use [fs.unlink(path, callback)](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_unlink_path_callback) function. Here is an example of the function wrapper with "error-back" pattern:

```js
// Dependencies.
const fs = require('fs');

// Delete a file.
const deleteFile = (filePath, callback) => {
  // Unlink the file.
  fs.unlink(filePath, (error) => {
    if (!error) {
      callback(false);
    } else {
      callback('Error deleting the file');
    }
  })
};
```

Answer (score 3):

It's very easy with fs.

```
var fs = require('fs');
try{
 var sourceUrls = "/sampleFolder/sampleFile.txt";
 fs.unlinkSync(sourceUrls);
}catch(err){
 console.log(err);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use the `await` keyword without throwing if the file does not exist but do not want to use `try`/`catch`, you can use this one liner

```js
await unlink('/path/to/file').catch(() => void 0)
```

Comment: should be mentioned this is for fs/promises

Answer (score 2):

Remove files from the directory that matched regexp for filename. Used only fs.unlink - to remove file, fs.readdir - to get all files from a directory

```
var fs = require('fs');
const path = '/path_to_files/filename.anyextension'; 

const removeFile = (fileName) => {
    fs.unlink(`${path}${fileName}`, function(error) {
        if (error) {
            throw error;
        }
        console.log('Deleted filename', fileName);
    })
}

const reg = /^[a-zA-Z]+_[0-9]+(\s[2-4])+\./

fs.readdir(path, function(err, items) {
    for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
        console.log(items[i], ' ', reg.test(items[i]))
        if (reg.test(items[i])) {
           console.log(items[i])
           removeFile(items[i]) 
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`fs-extra` provides a remove method:

```
const fs = require('fs-extra')

fs.remove('/tmp/myfile')
.then(() => {
  console.log('success!')
})
.catch(err => {
  console.error(err)
})
```

https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra/blob/master/docs/remove.md

Answer (score 1):

**You can remove the file using the below codes:**

Import the `unlinkSync`:

```
import { unlinkSync } from 'fs';
```

**Can create a method like this:**

```
export const removeFileFromLocation = async (filePath: string) => {
    const removeRes = await unlinkSync(filePath);
    return removeRes;
}
```

**Use this method as:**

```
const removeRes = await removeFileFromLocation(`${PATH_DOWNLOADED_FILE}/${sourceFileName}`);
console.log("removeFileFromLocation:",removeRes);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's the most minified code I found which doesn't cause errors:

```js
fs.rm(filePath,()=>{})
```

Unfortunately, the callback '()=>{}' is necessary to avoid errors, which I think is stupid, but whatever, it works!

Comment: if we're talking minified may I offer a one-character saving :¬D `fs.rm(filePath,_=>{})`

Comment: I have thought about that, and I like your line of thinking, and I do use it for arrow functions with a single input, but this creates a new temporary variable unnecessarily, so I wouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

Use [NPM module fs-extra](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-extra), which gives you everything in fs, plus everything is Promisified.  As a bonus, there's a [fs.remove() method](https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra/blob/master/docs/remove.md) available.

Answer (score 0):

Those who trying to find a way to do the same in a module file, you can check out [fs-extra](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-extra).

```js
import fs from 'fs-extra'
```

This will allow you to use any of the above-quoted methods defined by `fs`, there are various async actions also supported by it.

Answer (score 0):

#### Promise example

Promise-based operations return a promise that is fulfilled when the asynchronous operation is complete.

```js
import { unlink } from 'node:fs/promises';

try {
  await unlink('/tmp/hello');
  console.log('successfully deleted /tmp/hello');
} catch (error) {
  console.error('there was an error:', error.message);
}
```

#### Callback example

The callback form takes a completion callback function as its last argument and invokes the operation asynchronously. The arguments passed to the completion callback depend on the method, but the first argument is always reserved for an exception. If the operation is completed successfully, then the first argument is null or undefined.

```js
import { unlink } from 'node:fs';

unlink('/tmp/hello', (err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('successfully deleted /tmp/hello');
});
The callback-based versions of the node:fs module APIs are preferable over the use of the promise APIs when maximal performance (both in terms of execution time and memory allocation) is required.
```

#### Synchronous example

The synchronous APIs block the Node.js event loop and further JavaScript execution until the operation is complete. Exceptions are thrown immediately and can be handled using try…catch, or can be allowed to bubble up.

```py
import { unlinkSync } from 'node:fs';

try {
  unlinkSync('/tmp/hello');
  console.log('successfully deleted /tmp/hello');
} catch (err) {
  // handle the error
}
```

[see more](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_file_system)

Answer (score -2):

Here the code where you can delete file/image from folder.

```
var fs = require('fs'); 
Gallery.findById({ _id: req.params.id},function(err,data){ 
    if (err) throw err;
    fs.unlink('public/gallery/'+data.image_name);
 });
```

Comment: Since node 7 the callback argument is no longer optional and will result in a warning. Pass an empty function if you really don't care about it.