# Multer create new folder with data

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multipart, multer

I use [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer).

#### Question 1

When I put the following snippet in the `app.js`

```
app.use(multer({
        dest: './uploads'
    }
).single('file'));
```

it creates a new folder under the root folder, my question is about this new folder's lifeCycle, When it'll be deleted? How much the size of the folder could be after 100 call?

#### Question 2

If I don't want to limit the file size, what I should put in the configuration?

```
app.use(multer({
    dest: './public/profile/img/',
    limits: {
        fieldNameSize: 50,
        files: 1,
        fields: 5,
        fileSize: 1024 * 1024
    },
```

**Update**

My app is built like

app.js file contain

```
    app.use(multer({
            dest: './uploads'
        }
    ).single('file'));

app.use('/', routes, function (req, res, next) {
    next();
});
```

The route file look like following

```
appRouter
    .post('*', function (req, res) {
        handler.dispatch(req, res)
    })
    .get('*', function (req, res) {
        handler.dispatch(req, res)
    })
```

And in third file I use the unzip like following

```
update: function (req, res) {
  var filePath = path.join(req.file.destination, req.file.filename);
            var unzipper = new Unzipper(filePath);
            unzipper.on("extract", function () {
                console.log("Finished extracting");
                res.sendStatus(200);
            });
            unzipper.on('progress', function (fileIndex, fileCount) {
                console.log('Extracted file ' + (fileIndex + 1) + ' of ' + fileCount);
            });
            unzipper.on('list', function (files) {
                console.log('The archive contains:');
                console.log(files);
            });

            unzipper.on('error', function (err) {
                console.log('Caught an error', err);
            });

            unzipper.extract({
                path: "./"
            });
        }
```

The below is how my node Application is structured, can someone please advice how and where(which file) its **recommended** to use the Raf code with adding a dateTime to the file which I can add sorting ...

Comment: Can you please explain the first question in a better way? I have used Multer before.

Comment: Not limiting the file size is a bad idea; you're basically asking for a DoS attack.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I will try to answer your question with a real life example, at least you might learn some stuff from it. If you wish to delete all except the most recent upload, then you need to code some sort of logic to differentiate between which upload is recent and which ones are old. Below I describe, how I would go about solving this issue, might not be perfect but, that is how I do it.

*The folder will never be deleted automatically, unless you delete it either manually or programmatically.*

*The size of folder with 100 calls assuming that in each call you upload a file of x size would be x multiplied by 100*

*You don't want to limit the file upload, don't supply limits configs, however it is recommended to specify a file upload limit.*

You can obviously attach the multer to the app or create an instance of it and pass that to a route. I prefer the second method:

**multer config**

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, 'uploads/')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    var filename = file.originalname;
    var fileExtension = filename.split(".")[1];
    cb(null, Date.now() + "." + fileExtension);
  }
});
```

As shown above, I do not let multer give a random name to the uploaded file. What I do is, get the file name, strip off its extension and then use `Date.now()` which will give me the current timestamp appended with the uploaded file extension. If I make six uploads, they would show as follow (most of my uploads were .jpg, that's taken from filename).

**How upload would end up (timestamps would differ)**

```
1453414099665.jpg (oldest) 
1453414746114.JPG
1453414748991.jpg
1453414751662.jpg
1453414754815.jpg (most recent)
```

I attached the above `storage` to an instance of multer as follow:

```
var upload = multer({storage: storage});
```

Now I can pass the `upload` to a route which handle the file upload as follow:

**attach upload to route as shown below**

```
//simple route to return upload form, simple jade file
app.get('/upload', function(req, res){
  res.render('upload');
});

//this route processes the upload request, see below upload.single('file') 
//is the passed multer
app.post('/upload', upload.single('file'),  function(req,res){
  res.status(204).end();
});
```

Let's say you keep uploading and then at some point you want to list all files in the uploads directory. The route would be as follow:

**List all files in uploads directory**

```
//lists all files in the uploads directory and return it to browser as json response
app.get('/listAllFiles', function(req, res) {
  //reading directory in synchronous way
  var files = fs.readdirSync('./uploads');
  res.json(files);
});
```

You want to delete all files in the upload directory, the route would look as follow:

**Delete all files in uploads directory**

```
//delete all files in the upload direcotry asynchronously
app.get('/deleteAllFiles', function(req, res) {
  fs.readdir('./uploads', function(err, items) {
    items.forEach(function(file) {
        fs.unlink('./uploads/' + file);
        console.log('Deleted ' + file);
    });
    res.status(204).end();
  });
});
```

If you wish to delete all files synchronously then you have to invoke the sync version of readdir (readdirSync) and unlink (unlinkSync)

```
var filenames = fs.readdirSync('./uploads');

filenames.forEach(function(file) {
  fs.unlinkSync('./uploads/' + file);
});
```

Now to your point of deleting all but, the most recent uploaded file. Well, I have already made all filename be timestamps. So I would do something as follow:

Delete all files except most recent (where most recent being the one with most recent timestamp as its filename).

```
//delets all file asynchronously except the most recent in which case the file
//with name being the latest timestamp is skipped.
app.get('/deleteAllExceptMostRecent', function(req, res) {
  console.log('/deleteAllFilesExceptMostRecent');
  fs.readdir('./uploads', function(err, items) {
    //sort the array of files names in reverse, so we have most recent file on top
    items.reverse();
    var flag = true;

    items.forEach(function(file) {
      //skip deletion of most recent file. if condition executed onces only.
      if(flag) {
        flag = false;
      } else {
        fs.unlink('./uploads/' + file);
        console.log('Deleted ' + file);
      }
    });
  });
  res.status(204).end();
});
```

I have not added any limits in my example but, it is recommended. The default file size limit is infinity and if you don't include it in a prod environment then you will be vulnerable to DoS attacks as indicated in the comments.

For the above file operation to work you need to load

```
var fs = require('fs');
```

In regards to your second point, simply skip the limits property and the default limit will be infinity.

For demonstration purposes, I have setup the above in a working nodejs app, see below:

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var multer = require('multer');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');

var app = new express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, 'uploads/')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    /* if you need to retain the original filename, then use filename and append to it date
     * if you don't need original filename but, just extension, then append extension at the
     * end of current timestamp. If you don't need extenion then just use Date.now() which
     */
    var filename = file.originalname;
    var fileExtension = filename.split(".")[1];

    cb(null, Date.now() + "." + fileExtension);
  }
})

var upload = multer({storage: storage});

//get upload form
app.get('/upload', function(req, res){
  res.render('upload');
});

//process upload
app.post('/upload', upload.single('file'),  function(req,res){
  res.status(204).end();
});

//lists all files in the uploads directory.
app.get('/listAllFiles', function(req, res) {
  var files = fs.readdirSync('./uploads');
  res.json(files);
});

//delete all files in the upload direcotry asynchronously
app.get('/deleteAllFiles', function(req, res) {
  fs.readdir('./uploads', function(err, items) {
    items.forEach(function(file) {
        fs.unlink('./uploads/' + file);
        console.log('Deleted ' + file);
    });
    res.status(204).end();
  });
});

//delets all file asynchronously except the most recent in which case the file
//with name being the latest timestamp is skipped.
app.get('/deleteAllExceptMostRecent', function(req, res) {
  console.log('/deleteAllFilesExceptMostRecent');
  fs.readdir('./uploads', function(err, items) {
    items.reverse();
    var flag = true;

    items.forEach(function(file) {
      if(flag) {
        flag = false;
      } else {
        fs.unlink('./uploads/' + file);
        console.log('Deleted ' + file);
      }
    });
  });
  res.status(204).end();
});

//delete all files of a direcotry in synchronous way
app.get('/deleteAllSync', function(req, res) {
  var filenames = fs.readdirSync('./uploads');

  filenames.forEach(function(file) {
    fs.unlinkSync('./uploads/' + file);
  });
});

//delete all files except most recent in synchronous way
app.get('/deleteAllSyncExceptMostRecent', function(req, res) {
  var filenames = fs.readdirSync('./uploads');
  filenames.reverse();
  var flag = true;
  filenames.forEach(function(file) {
    if(flag) 
      flag = false;
    else
      fs.unlinkSync('./uploads/' + file);
  });
});

var port = 3000;
app.listen( port, function(){ console.log('listening on port '+port); } );
```

**views/upload.jade**

```
html
  head
    title
  body
    form(method="post",enctype="multipart/form-data",action="/upload")
      p
        input(type="file",name="file")
      p
        input(type="submit")
```

Comment: Thanks Raf 1+,please see my update I like the idea to give some timestemp to the file which enable the sorting by older, can you please suggest after my update where to put the multer config(with the storage) ? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you assist please ?

Comment: You could change this bit of your code **app.use(multer({dest: './uploads'}).single('file'));** to something **app.use(upload);** and above this you have to copy/paste the definition of upload which I have shown in my answer. That is one way to do it, basically you tell app to use a multer object that contains storage definition. The other way and maybe more simple would be to comment out your own **app.use(multer** and then just above the router.post copy/paste the storage and multer definition and pass it to router as 2nd arg **app.post('/upload', upload.single('file'),  function(req,res){**

Comment: Thanks I need to use the first option but not sure how to combine the app.use(upload)with what I already have (app.use(multer({des.... ) can you please give an example and I'll try it now ?Thank you!

Comment: replace **app.use(multer({dest....}))** with **app.use(upload)** they are the same thing after all, in your approach you define multer inside app.use but, in my approach, i define multer seperately and then pass it to app.use (obviously you have to place the storage and upload definitions above app.use(upload) for it to work.

Comment: I don't have your code to give it a try but, if not mistaken rather than just passing upload to the **app.use(upload)** you should pass **app.use(upload.single('file'))** see the answer for this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31496100/cannot-app-usemulter-requires-middleware-function-error it explains it well enough

Comment: I'll try it now and let you know btw where its recommended to put the code ofvar storage = multer.diskStorage({ ... ?  in the app.js ?

Comment: Well it is up to you whether or not to use storage, basically storage gives you more control over how files are stored see the multer docs https://github.com/expressjs/multer you can skip the storage if you want too. See the link which I provided you in earlier comment, shows solutions without use of storage.

Answer (score 1):

**(1)** When you make the following call you are telling multer to place uploaded files into a directory called `uploads`. So it will create that dir for you if it's not already present when your app starts up.

```
app.use(multer({
        dest: './uploads'
    }
).single('file'));
```

In terms of that directory's life cycle, it will stay there as long as you don't delete it, and are still asking multer to use it as the destination. Uploaded files are being added there, so the size of its contents depends on what is being uploaded.

**(2)** As for limiting the file size, the default according to the docs is Infinity. So there is no limit unless you set one.

But, not knowing your application, I would still strongly suggest setting a limit, even if you need it to be fairly high. Removing the size limit altogether may lead to big problems.

---

**edit**
If you would like to delete the contents of `./uploads` when a new file is uploaded, Node provides a way to delete a file: [fs.unlink](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_unlink_path_callback). See also [SO about removing a file in node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5315138/node-js-remove-file)

In your upload handler, inspect the contents of `./uploads`, and `unlink` any file that is not the file used in the current request. See `req.file` for the current upload.

Comment: Thanks but can you please suggest how to delete this folder after several files are persisted there ,maybe to keep the new requests and delete the old...or better to start to do it when I've put some limit of the file size...

Comment: Do you mean that you would like to delete old files within `./uploads/` after a certain time limit? Or delete old files once the total size of all the files in the `./uploads/` directory passes a certain limit? You probably do not want to delete the `./uploads/` directory itself, right? Because then you would lose all the files uploaded and handled via multer.

Comment: I want to delete all the content in the folder but to keep the folder itslef with the last call entery inside how it can be done?

Comment: The following answer provides a way to delete the most recent file(s) in a directory: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34862475/1671886.

Answer (score 0):

**Que 1)** You can decide folders life cycle.

1. If you want to store files on server & retrive it back at any time without file size limit , u need bigger storage
2. If you are using third party like **Amazon S3** to store, no point in storing locally, as soon as its uploaded to server you can remove from local storage.
   You can use [after Hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20175806/before-and-after-hooks-for-a-request-in-express-to-be-executed-before-any-req-a) when response sent.

   ```
   app.use(function (req, res, next) {
   function afterResponse() {
       res.removeListener('finish', afterRequest);
       res.removeListener('close', afterRequest);

       // Delete files from multer 
       // you can delete older one from upload folder as you see new one came here.
   }

   res.on('finish', afterResponse);
   res.on('close', afterResponse);

   // action before request
   // eventually calling `next()`
    });
   ```

**Que 2)** Default is limitless.