# Displaying images from node(server) to angular 2?

Tags: node.js, angular

I'm uploading files from Angular 2 with [ngx-uploader](https://github.com/bleenco/ngx-uploader) and storing them on backend (nodejs/feathers) with multer. Now I'm having trouble to reach and display them, for now im just trying to display image, but actually i just need to see how paths work so i can reach the .pdf files.
As a file path im getting this: resources\\uploads\\quality-docs\\FILENAME so i tried to reach them like this: http://localhost:3030/resources/uploads/quality-docs/FILENAME but it doesnt work, it gives me 404. Just realised when i put files in static, public folder, i can reach it like http://localhost:3030/FILENAME ... but is there a way for it to not be in public?

This is how my backend structure looks like: [image]

Any ideas/sugestions are welcome, is this even a right way to go? Plus if any of you have idea how to delete files from server?

Comment: Are you using express as your web server on node.js? If so, take a look at http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html to add a new static route to the resources/uploads directory.

Comment: Also, to delete the files use `unlink` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5315138/node-js-remove-file

Comment: wow thanks a lot pal!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are using express in your node app, you need to include a static route to the resources/uploads directory ([express static routes](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)) like the following:

```
app.use(express.static('resources/uploads'))
```

For deleting files from a node application use `unlink` [fs.unlink](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_unlink_path_callback)